# Remove first line from a text file using XSLT

Tags: xslt, flat-file

I'm working with a system (Maximo) that generates a text file.
I need to remove just the first line of the file.
The way to do that should be using XSLT.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can accomplish what you want in XSLT!**

It would probably be easier to do so in XSLT 2.0, if that is an option for you.  [Michael Kay answered a similar question on the XSL mailing list in 2005.](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200508/msg00085.html)

Paraphrasing his answer, with small examples:

**In XSLT 2.0,**: you can use the [unparsed-text()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text) function to read the file, [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) to split it into lines (and just ignore the first line).

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($in), '\r?\n')">
 ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

**In XSLT 1.0**: you can read a flat text file by pretending that it's an XML
external entity, and referencing it from an XML document that causes the
entity to be expanded.

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "bar.txt">
]>
<foo>
&bar;
</foo>
```

Comment: Very cool trick with the entity reference! I hope it works for him. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is **not** using XSLT.

XSLT can *produce* text files, but it cannot *process* text files.  It can only process well-formed XML.

Comment: The way to do that is not using XSLT. -- Agreed but right now it's the only viable option.

Comment: @NitroxDM — That's what each of the answers here is trying to say — *if XSLT is the **only** tool you have, it cannot be done*.  You **must** involve some other tool to accomplish your goal, and if you can involve another tool at all, then you have an avenue to use something more appropriate than XSLT.

Comment: @Ben Blank - An XSLT solution IS TOTALLY possible.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT will only take a valid XML file as input, not a general text file. It can output text, though.

(I use XSLT to generate C code, for example.)

Comment: XSLT 2.0 can process non-XML files using the unparsed-text() function and XSLT 1.0 can be tricked into working with plain text by using it as an entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your XSLT processor supports any-to-any transformation(binary xforms via FFDs - Flat File Descriptors), there is a possibility of doing this. You can wrap your text in a node and then operate on that node using a regular XSLT template to output whatever is after the first carriage return.

Comment: Could one wrap the contents of the text file into a node using XSLT?

Comment: @NitroxDM — Catch-22.  If a file needs to be processed before you can use it with XSLT, you cannot use XSLT to do that processing.

Comment: Depending on your processor/platform - WebSphere DataPower (an SOA Appliance) supports that - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14107417